# Fast way to find indexes of nonzero entries for every row in a CSC matrix in Python

Tags: python, numpy, sparse-matrix

Here's the current implementation:

```
def nonzero_indexes_by_row(input):
    return [
        np.nonzero(row)[1] 
        for row in csr_matrix(input.T)
    ]
```

The matrix is very large(1.5M, 500K), since I'm accessing rows, I have to convert CSC to CSR first. The result would be a 2d list, each list contains a list of indexes that are nonzero corresponding to the row in the original matrix.

The current process takes 20 minutes. Is there a faster way?

Comment: Converting the `csc` to `lil` will give you `rows` that is an object array of the desired lists.  For the big matrix the conversion might still take time.

Comment: @hpaulj Can you elaborate a bit more on how this would improve the performance?

Comment: In your example is `input` a `CSC` matrix or a `CSR` matrix? Because if it's `CSC`, `input.T` will be a `CSR` matrix anyway.

Comment: @CJR The original matrix is CSR, but I need to find the nonzero indices by column, to make it faster, I could either convert it to CSC and iterate over columns, or transpose it and convert if to CSR. I did the latter. Please let me know if there's any problem with that. I am fairly new with numpy.

Comment: Ahh. I don't know what problem you're trying to solve here, but a list of lists at scale is a very bad idea. It's hard to manipulate and very memory intensive (since every item is a pointer to something instead of an element of a contiguous array). You should seriously reconsider the approach that has brought you to this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. You're pretty close to having an ideal solution, but you're allocating some unnecessary arrays. Here's a faster way:

```py
from scipy import sparse
import numpy as np

def my_impl(csc):
    csr = csc.tocsr()
    return np.split(csr.indices, csr.indptr[1:-1])

def your_impl(input):
    return [
        np.nonzero(row)[1] 
        for row in sparse.csr_matrix(input)
    ]

## Results

# demo data
csc = sparse.random(15000, 5000, format="csc")

your_result = your_impl(csc)
my_result = my_impl(csc)

## Tests for correctness

# Same result
assert all(np.array_equal(x, y) for x, y in zip(your_result, my_result))
# Right number of rows
assert len(my_result) == csc.shape[0]

## Speed

%timeit my_impl(csc)
# 31 ms ± 1.26 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit your_impl(csc)
# 1.49 s ± 19.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Side question, why are you transposing the matrix? Wouldn't you then be getting the non-zero entries of the columns? If that's what you want, you don't even need to convert to `csr` and can just run:

```py
np.split(csc.indices, csc.indptr[1:-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

An interesting alternative to your code is to convert your array to
the *COOrdinate* format and then read its *row* and *col* attributes:

```
def nonzero_indices_by_coo(input):
    cx = input.T.tocoo()
    res = [ [] for i in range(cx.shape[0]) ]
    for i, j in zip(cx.row, cx.col):
        res[i].append(j)
    return res
```

It returns a list of plain *pythonic* lists, instead of *Numpy* arrays,
but this should not be any important difference.

I noticed that your code uses internally transposition of the source array
(*T* operator) so I did the same in my code.

To compare execution speed, I created the following sparse array (*2000* by *300*):

```
r = 2000; c = 300
x = scipy.sparse.lil_matrix( (r,c) )
for _ in range(r):
    x[np.random.randint(0,r-1), np.random.randint(0,c-1)] = np.random.randint(1,100)
```

and my code ran about 12 times faster than yours.

## Yet quicker solution (in other format)

Or maybe it will be better to generate a *2-D* (*Numpy*) array,
with 2 rows:

- first row - row indices of consecutive non-zero elements,
- second row - column indices.

To generate such result, you can use the following code:

```
def nonzero_indices_2d(input):
    cx = input.T.tocoo()
    return np.array([cx.row, cx.col])
```

which runs 4 times faster than my first solution.

Of course, then other parts of your code should be reworked, to consume
the indices given in another format.

Sparse arrays have also its **own** *nonzero* method:

```
arr.nonzero()
```

generating a 2-row *Numpy* array of indices. This function runs yet
a few percent faster.

So, assuming that the *2-D* result format is acceptable (instead of
a list of lists), maybe you don't need any own function to get these
indices.

Another detail to consider: Whether (in all versions) there should be
used transposition.
Your choice, but without transposition each version
of code would run a bit faster.

Comment: I do have to use the exact output format, list of lists with nonzero indices. If I follow this approach, I will need to add the overhead of the output format conversion, would it still be faster? I'll probably just iterate over the covered indices and construct the list with appends. Do you have any faster ways for the output conversion that would make the overall process faster?

Comment: Compare the execution time of *input.nonzero()* and your code.
In my environment it was about 48 times shorter, so from 20 minutes (for your code) it should be shortened to about 25 seconds.
I think, this is a sufficient rationale for reworking your code to consume indices of non-zero elements.
Looking for the way to speed up your code, consider also yet another *scipy.sparse* method, namely *find*. It returns both indices of non-zero elements and these elements
themselves.

Comment: Look at the `lil` `x.rows`.  Also look at the `arr.nonzero` code.  It basically returns the `coo` attrivutes.